# Identifying three species of Datura

Tags: species-identification, botany, plant-anatomy, toxicology, flowers

I have found a large, wild patch, some 200m long, of mainly Datura Stramonium, in our street. I have always been keenly interested and well read on the shamanic, and - very rare - medicinal uses of this species, but scattered amongst them, like family, are two other plants I don't know, but am convinced are also some kind of Datura. I would please like some help on identifying the other two based on the two photos I have of all three.

[image: What I know as the Stramonium Flower]

This is the well known - to me - Stramonium flower, the plant characterized by jagged leaves and the well known spiked seed pod of Jimson Weed seeds.

[image: Morning Flory - Flowers, leaf, and other foliage]

It looks like user29734's answer is correct, and the above is Morning Glory, but of course subject to confirmation. I now do recognize at least the purple flower as Morning Glory, but from some 30 odd years ago. And it now looks like what I confused with Datura Alba is really just another colour flower of the Morning Glory.

If anyone could please confirm my ID of the Stramonium, and confirm the identification of the second image as morning glory, and suggest what species.

These plants are all around my neighbourhood, with is the northern part of Randburg, South Africa. This city borders on the Northern side of Johannesburg. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVj43.jpg) It's a temperate climate, with very hot and rainy summers, and bitterly cold and dry winters. The soil is reddish and lacks much humus.

It is a semi-rural area, having been rapidly urbanised over the last ten or so years, when it was still just farms and small holdings. Farming is mainly vegetables or lucerne; and lots of maize further out from the city. We are a few km south of the [Cradle of Humankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cradle_of_Humankind).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVj43.jpg) Strangely enough, there are two cities in the US with the same names, both in California, I believe. I know Johannesburg is.

Comment: In the second photo none is *Datura*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and where you saw these plants. Location is often very relevant when attempting to identify species.

Comment: Could the second photo be a Convulvulus/Calystegia?

Comment: @RHA, no, the flowers are far less flat and cone like, but wide, not like the narrow Stramonium trumpet shape. I only have dried ones with me now, but I will find a very good example tomorrow and photograph it well, isolated from the foliage, with separate pics of the latter.

Comment: @terdon I have added as much detail as I could guess you wanted. I'm no biologist, so only have a rough idea of which factors count, so a tried a shotgun approach.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Yet they are densely interspersed with the Datura, with zero gaps and much overlapping of branches, and I have not seen them elsewhere.

Comment: @ProfK to me it seems the pink flower at second photo is from any species of [*Ipomoea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea) [(Convulvulaceae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolvulaceae). The cordate leaves are seemingly of the same plant, or may be from some-other plant.

Comment: Yes, the second photo looks to me like a morning glory (Ipomoea).  Is it a vine?  The third appears identical to what I have growing as datura in my own garden.

Comment: @jamesqf Sorry for the OT, but how do you find growing Datura in you garden? I would imagine in requires quite frequent pruning. I wish to start doing the same.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused The leaves are definitely of the same plant, as I have picked flowers from the same stems as leaves.

Comment: @ProfK  why you removed the third image? Seemingly that was some sort of *Datura*.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Because it turns out that is not a picture of the plant I was trying to identify, which is just a whitish type of ipomoea.

Comment: [this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/92KbL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92KbL.png)? quite strongly looks like *Datura* (as also wrote by @jamesqf). The shape of corolla and calyx looks same as *Datura*, including projections at margin of corolla. The stamens are same in length; and style is so long... it is quite unexpected in Ipomoea. Also it may look similar to *Mirabilis jalapa*, but it is not.

Comment: @ProfK: It does take a bit of space, but my garden is about an acre.  I do need to regularly prune the seed pods off before they're ripe (every few weeks during the summer/fall), or it will reseed quite enthusiastically.  They plants die back to the ground in winter here (USDA zone 6/7).  Very good nighttime fragrance.

Comment: The two left pictures look like garden morning glories, which are mostly hybrids of various species, some of which reseed quite well in my garden, and could have become naturalized.  The leaves on the right look something like Ipomoea leptophylla, but that's native to the US Great Plains area: https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=IPLE and not common in commerce.  But there are a lot of Ipomoea species, and I'm no expert, just a gardener.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused It does, but the shape of the leaves in the image you linked to don't match the rounder leaves in my centre-bottom pic.

Comment: Yes the third plant (https://i.stack.imgur.com/92KbL.png) (seems to be  *Datura*) is completely different from the second one (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkbpT.png) which is certainly NOT datura. And *Datura* indeed shows drastic variations in leaf size and teeth-depth in different populations of it.

Comment: There is no third plant. All three bottom photos are flowers, leaf, and end of stem foliage from the same plant, and the other plant being the top picture, Stramonium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so as far as the blue and white flower goes I'm pretty sure it's a cultivar of ipomoea called Flying Saucer which is a hybrid of heavenly blue (I. tricolor) and Pearly gates (also I. tricolor) meaning it's a hybrid and no seed output. 
As far as the white flowers go it is most likely Datura since it is part of a short shrub and the petals are spiked. However you should determine if it blooms at night because its possible it could be moonflower. It may also be brugsmansia or pearly gates. 
As far as 'alchemical use' datura contains scopolamine which is potentially lethal if consumed in indiscriminate amounts.

Comment: I am only too aware of the potentially fatal  and extreme effects of scopolamine, both from extensive study and several very interesting personal experiences. The best treatment for an unexpected or unwanted scopolamine experience is physostigmine and acetylcysteine, for the anticholinergic poisoning, and benzodiazepines for the extremely elevated heart rate. Physostigmine occurs naturally in the Calabar bean.

Answer (score 3):

The second flower is, I'm guessing by the valentine shaped leaf and violet tubular flowers, a morning glory vine (ipomoea violacea or ipomea tricolor). These plants both are closely related cultivars of ololioqui and tlitlitzen which had a history of shamanic use in southern Mexico.

Comment: Aaha,, yes, I think I now do recognize that from them growing in a friend's yard when I was very young. So all the psycho-active plants stick together then, like mafiosi.

Comment: @ProfK yes, oddly. The morning glory species contains lysergamide and and it's analogues. However, there is a plant which is native from Carola all the way down to Micronesia called Argyria nervosa which contains the same active principle as the mesoamerican plants.

Comment: I have edited my question, and included much better images of the ipomoea flowers, of two colours, a leaf, and some other foliage at the top of a 700 - 1000 mm high stem where the thin vines with leaves and flowers start.

Comment: That said, as I am studying this plant as an alchemist, where would I locate seeds on the ipomoea?

Comment: The seeds on ipomoea form after the flower dies. It sort of dissolves because of its structure and a bulb begins to grow at the ovule. You can observe this as sepal will begin to bulge. You will begin to see a greenish looking pod emerge but you want to extract the seeds from it only when the pod dries and becomes brown. This is assuming that the plant is not a hybrid. If it has grape shaped leaves and heart shaped leaves it won't produce seeds at all. Fascinating, I suggest you read psychology and alchemy by Jung and gionardo bruno and the hermetic tradition by Frances Yates. Excellent books.

Comment: Thanks for advice and the great suggestions, especially Jung, who is fairly  unique amongst modern psychologists to not discard and instead value the ancient and evolved bodies of knowledge in magick and alchemy. I am myself a Hermeticist and in particular a Thelemite.

Answer (score 0):

The top plant looks like it could easily be D. stramonium. Daturas can be a bit tricky. You should either provide an estimate of the scale or measure the flower, then compare with this simple key of invasive Daturas (in Australia): https://www.samorini.it/doc1/alt_aut/ek/haegi.pdf. It helps to note capsule size and shape. (It is NOT a Brugmansia sp.; those are trees with pendant flowers.) Also, the second flower photo seems to me is clearly a morning glory, possibly as IDed by user29734, and the center leaf seems from the same plant(s) or closely related.